# C++ arrays select square number and make new vector

Tags: c++, arrays, cube

I have to see which of the following from a vector is a square number then make another vector with only the square numbers 
For example: (4,15,6,25,7,81) the second will be (4,25,81)

4,25,81 because 2x2=4 5x5=25 and 9x9=81

I started like this:

```
{

    int A[100],n,r,i;
    cout<<"Number of elements=";
    cin>>n;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"A["<<i<<"]=";
        cin>>A[i];
    }
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            r=sqrt(A[i]);
            if(r*r==A[i])


    }

return 0;

}
```

but I am not really sure how to continue

Comment: Do you mean perfect *squares*?

Comment: yes i did, sorry, my mistake

Comment: [`std::vector<int> squares;`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) then `squares.push_back(A[i]);`.

Answer (score 4):

There's an algorithm for that:

```
std::copy_if(inputs.begin(), inputs.end(), std::back_inserter(squares),
   [](int N) {int s=(int)sqrt(N); return s*s==N; });
```

You might want to elaborate on that a little, such as either changing from `int` to `unsigned`, or immediately returning `false` for negative numbers (unless you want to involve complex numbers, not just integers).

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know before hand how many integers the user will enter or how many of those will actually be squares, you should probably use dynamic array allocation (or even better, use a container like std::vector).

```
int A[],n,r,i, numSquares = 0;
cout<<"Number of elements=";
cin>>n;

if(n>MAX_NUMBERS) {
  // error: user wants to enter too many integers
}

A = new[n];  // dynamically allocate array

for(i=0;i<n;i++)  // array indexing ranges from 0 to n-1
{
    cout<<"A["<<i<<"]=";
    cin>>A[i];
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    r=sqrt(A[i]);
    if(r*r!=A[i]) {  // A[i] is not a square, "erase" it
      A[i] = INT_MAX;
    } else {
      ++numSquares;  // A[i] is a square, leave it alone
    }
}

// collect all squares not "erased" in a new array
int squares[] = new int[numSquares], j=0;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  if(A[i]!=INT_MAX)
    squares[j++] = A[i];

delete [] A;
delete [] squares;
```